# How would i make flip card compatible with other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, safari, cross-browser

new here

I am making a website and would like it to be compatible with all browsers so far I've got this flip card for a profile section however whenever I try it on safari or another browser which isn't google chrome it goes haywire and shows both back and front. If anyone could provide help or guidance that would be much-appreciated thanks.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
  z-index: 2;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
</head>
<body>

<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may need to use `-webkit-`  and `-moz-` for some of those newer CSS properties. Different browsers use different rendering engines so there will likely be some difference in their animated behavior unless you set explicit rules for each user agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refer example below which is compatible with **IE, MS Edge, Chrome, FireFox and Safari** browsers.

Code:

```css
#container {
 position:relative;
 height:300px;
 width:300px;
 margin:20px auto;
}

#container > div {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 padding:20px;
 background:#3C404B;
 -webkit-transition:1.5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:1.5s ease-in-out;
 transition:1.5s ease-in-out;
}

#container > div.lower {
 background:#000;
 -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
 -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
 backface-visibility:hidden;
 -moz-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
 -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
 transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
}

#container > div h1 {
 font-size:20px;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 color:#fff;
 line-height:40px;
}

#container > div p {
 font-size:11px;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 color:#eee;
 line-height:20px;
}

#container > div a {
 color:#ff0;
}

#container > div.upper {
 -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
 -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
 backface-visibility:hidden;
 -moz-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
 -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
 transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
}

#container:hover > div.lower {
 -moz-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
 -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
 transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
}

#container:hover > div.upper {
 -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(-179.9deg);
 -moz-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(-179.9deg);
 transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(-179.9deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div class="lower">
  <h1>Back</h1>
  <p>Works in IE10, Chrome, Firefox & Safari</p>
  <p>Source <a href="https://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-3d-card.html">CssPlay</a>
 </div>
 <div class="upper">
  <h1>Front</h1>
  <p>Works in IE10, Chrome, Firefox & Safari</p>
  <p>Source <a href="https://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-3d-card.html">CssPlay</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Reference:

[Flip Card Example link](https://codepen.io/pingmintech/pen/Kbmuk)

Further, You can try to modify the code as per your own requirement.